# HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post

I am tried to Post String value to Sql Server.like this

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?&name=%@&password=%@&pin=%@&email=%@&phone=%@&address=%@&city=%@&status=%@",
                     name, password ,pin ,email ,phone,address,city,status];
    NSLog(@"post%@",post);
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://202.65.154.108:8080/SaveDollar/rest/deals/add"]]];

    NSLog(@"getData%@",request);

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSLog(@"getData%@",request);


    con3 = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(con3)
    {      webData3=[NSMutableData data];
        NSLog(@"Connection successful");
        NSLog(@"GOOD Day My data %@",webData3);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"connection could not be made");
    }
```

I tried like this connection successful.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSString *responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData3 encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseText);}
```

But get Response like this HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

I am not understand What my mistake so Please give me any idea,and Please tell me What wrong in my code.

Thanks in Advanced .

Answer (score 1):

**5xx Server Error**

**HTTP 500 Internal Server Error**

A generic error message, given when an unexpected condition was encountered and no more specific message is suitable. Source of this [**Wikipedia** : - List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and [**w3.org** Status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRESP.html)

So need to check on server side. It's not your issue.

Comment: I am also getting "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request." this error, have checked all perimeters are same as android ?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 500 Internal error (or) internal server error

It is meant that the error may be on several reasons
- The fault may be from server side i.e Json
- The fault may be from your side in which the parameters which you are sending may be in correct format which is expected from server
- The fault may be coding side which leads to crash